# WooCommerce delay emails on virtual products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it somehow possible to delay the order completed emails that is being send out at once, when a customer buys a virtual products? I would like to add a 2 hours delay to this.

Comment: You can add 2 hours with current `timediff` to send the email.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this Lenin?

Comment: You can take lesson from the delay saving RSS on this post https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/25-extremely-useful-tricks-for-the-wordpress-functions-file/